# Plot legend and remove some value of index

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, legending

I'm having two problems with this code.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Block[{t = 
   Table[(-1 + a - a d)/((1 + b) (-1 + d)), {a, -3, 3, 0.5}, {b, -3, 
     3, 0.5}]}, Plot[t, {d, 0, 0.99}]]
```

The first problem is how to remove the value of b = -1 from the list. With this I can use Join or something but it's also related to the second problem and making it harder.
The second problem is how to plot legend for different pair  of a, b (with b is different from -1)?

Comment: try  replacing `{b, -3,  3, 0.5}` with `{b, DeleteCases[Range[-3, 3, 0.5], -1.]}`?

Comment: @kglr it doesn't work if I change the step of b to 1. {b, DeleteCases[Range[-3, 3, 1], -1.]}

Comment: anhnha, use `1.` (instead of `1`) as the step size; or use `{b, DeleteCases[Range[-3, 3, 0.5], -1]}`

Comment: re legend, if you _really_ want 156 legends you can try `Block[{t = 
   Join @@ Table[Legended[(-1 + a - a d)/((1 + b) (-1 + d)), {a, b}], {a, -3, 3, 
      0.5}, {b, DeleteCases[Range[-3, 3, 0.5], -1.]}]}, 
 Plot[Evaluate@t, {d, 0, 0.99}]]`

Comment: whoa, thank you. it's much more than I thought. How come it generate 156 legends?

Comment: because there are that many combinations of `a` and `b`; try `Length[Join@@Table[foo,{a, -3, 3, 0.5}, {b, DeleteCases[Range[-3, 3, 0.5], -1.]}]` is 156`

Comment: I see. Let's try to see if I can simplify that function it first

Comment: @kglr do you know how can I assign for each line a number and then add this number to the legend in addition to its color?
So with each line there's at least two info like number and color so it's easier to see which one is which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recommend that you look at using [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate@
   Table[
    Tooltip[
     (-1 + a - a d)/((1 + b) (-1 + d)),
     Row[{"a = ", a}]],
    {a, -3, 3, 0.5}],
  {d, 0, 0.99},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {Style["d", 12, Italic], None},
  PlotLegends -> Range[-3, 3, 0.5],
  PlotLabel -> Simplify@
    Rationalize[(-1 + a - a d)/((1 + b) (-1 + d))]],
 {{b, 0}, DeleteCases[Range[-3, 3, 0.5], -1.]},
 ControlType -> SetterBar]
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great. How can I plot only positive y axis? I tried to add PlotRange like {0,30} but this is good for some value of b but very bad of others because plot range is not optimized.
Also for the legend how can I show legend for both {a, b}?

Comment: Use `PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}`. The value of `b` is shown in the control (blue highlight).